# ooPHP - class extending issue

Tags: php, oop

I have an question regarding extending classes in php . Suppouse I have two classes such as -

class A

class B

class B extends class A

my question is :
when i will be instantiating the class B then if I need to include the class A too in the index.php ?

such as -

```
include('classes/a.class.php');
include('classes/b.class.php');
```

or -

```
include('classes/b.class.php');
```

will be enough

i am confused about it . please help me

Comment: Can't you give it a try ? :)

Comment: It's far, far easier just to use an autoloader

Comment: There is no good way to do this, cause autoloaders might include the wrong class b that isn't extending a. I really suggest you find another way of what you're trying to do. Change the name of b extending a, and perhaps look at traits or embedded classes?

Comment: @Random i tried but it showed class A is not found . but when I included the a.class.php it worked

Comment: @Xorifelse should i include the a.class.php file in the top of b.class.php file?

Comment: @M.Rashid So you got your answer. You must include both, or add the "include('classes/a.class.php');" in your class B... You should also use "include_once" to avoid loops...

Comment: thanks all for helping me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question:

Class B is already extending class A then you just need to include class B in index.php. 
Class B must be able to include class A to extend from class A in file B.class.php. So Class A is "already present" with class B when including Class B in index.php

Comment: but class A and class B is in different file

Comment: You can include Class A in the file of Class B and then make Class B extend from Class A. Later in your index.php file you will need to include only class B

Comment: What you can do is to create a file named classes.inc.php. In this file you just include all the classes you need.
Then on index.php you only need to include class.inc.php.

Comment: If you use "include" in different files, you should use "include_once" to prevent loops problems...

Comment: @zm455 but i think doing so it will slow down the processes

Comment: I'm not sure but I think using autoload will slow the process more than including directly your classes using include_once.

Answer (score 0):

If class B extends class A and includes the class B file already includes class A then you only need to include B.

Basically if you include a file A in file B, then any files included in A are included in B. So if a file C includes B it will also have A

Comment: i know that . but i want to know the best practices .btw thankyou

Comment: That is the best practice, no need to  include something twice and you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Mark Baker for letting me know about the autoloader. I have searched over the net and found something very useful . Here is the autoloader :

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    if(file_exists('classes/'.$class_name . '.class.php')) {
        require_once('classes/'.$class_name . '.class.php');    
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Unable to load '.$class_name);

    }

}
```

my classes are under classes folder . it automatically loads the classes need for running the script . Nothing is needed to include.

Comment: Consider using `composer` for autoloading. Don't use home-made solutions until you are forced to do so. Also, using `composer` has  benefits of using many available packages.